# SQL Injection Query

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am writing a report on SQL injection attacks. I've found an example on [Owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) as shown bellow.

Since this is an example and to me, it seems as a simple query getting a row with the specific ID, does it do anything else or my assumption is correct?

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE custID='" + 
request.getParameter("id") + "'";  
// Since this is an online example i don't know what getParameter("id") method does.
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point of SQL Injection:  it is about code *not* in the application being run.  Start with the Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: I think the example provided to you is a bad one. Instead of giving you a proper example of SQL injection, such as `OR 1 == 1;` (return *all* records), they provided what appears to be Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> to me it seems as a simple query getting a row with specific ID

Thats the magic of injection. The query **should** only get a row that fits a certain criteria that comes from a request (like a GET or POST from html for example).

So `request.getParameter("id")` provides a parameter submitted by the user (or a very bad guy).

Usually whoever wrote that peace of code expected something like this:

`id = 12`

which would result in

```sql
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE custID='12'
```

Now image what happens if the user (a bad one in this case) sends this instead:

```
id = 0'; DROP TABLE accounts; --
```

This would execute as

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE custID='0'; DROP TABLE accounts; --'
```

Step-by-step:

1. Make sure the intended query executes without error (`0`)
2. End the query before the intended point (`';`)
3. Inject your malicous code (`DROP TABLE accounts;`)
4. Make sure everything that is left of the original query is treated as a comment (`--`)

The problem in the OWASP example isn't the query itself, but the fact that parameters that come from 'outside' (`request.getParameter("id")`) are used to generate a query, without escaping any potential control characters.

This style of writing code basically allows any user to execute code on your SQL-Server.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this query is that the SQL is created dynamically. Request.getparameter is probably just a function which returns the id of the row for the specific web request.

But if the webpage allows filling this parameter through a text box or the function is called directly from JavaScript any value can be set in id.

This could contain any SQL statement, which with the correct authentication, could even contain 'DROP Database'

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getParameter("id")
```

will get a the parameter "id" from the http-request, e.g. for: http://test.com/?id=qwertz `request.getParameter("id")` will return "qwertz". SQL injection is possible in this case, since the value of this parameter wasn't checked at all and can contain anything